# Scipy Optimizer constraint using two arguments

Tags: python, optimization, scipy

I'm trying to maximize a utility function by finding the optimal `N` units a person would use. One of the constraints is that they have finite money, `m`. So I'm trying to set up a constraint where array of length 3, `N` times the prices, `P` also an array of length 3, cannot be greater than `m`.

Like the example as follows:

```
P = np.array([3,4,5])
N = np.array([1,2,1])
m = 50
sum(P*N) > m
```

For this optimization, `P` is given based on a previous optimization. Now here's my actual code:

```
cons_c = [{'type':'ineq', 'fun': lambda N: 10 - sum(np.round(N)*P)},{'type':'ineq', 'fun': lambda N: 24 - sum(N*T)}]
bnds = [(0.,None) for x in range(len(N))]
optimized_c = scipy.optimize.minimize(utility_c, N, (P,Q,T), method='SLSQP', bounds=bnds, constraints=cons_c)
```

**The function:**

```
def utility_c(N,P,Q,T):

    print "N: {0}".format(N)
    print "P: {0}".format(P)
    print "Q: {0}".format(Q)
    print "T: {0}".format(T)
    N = np.round(N)
    m = 10 - sum(N*P)
    b = sum(N*Q)
    t = 24 - sum(N*T)
    print "m in C: {0}".format(m)
    print "b: {0}".format(b)
    print "t: {0}".format(t)
    # if m < 0 or t < 0:
    #     return 0
    return 1/ ((b**0.3)*(t**0.7))+(5*(m**0.5))
```

The problem is I still get negative `m`!  So clearly I'm not passing the constraint properly. I'm guessing that it's because `P` isn't used properly?

**Output:**

```
N: [ 1.  1.  1.]
P: [  5.  14.   4.]
Q: [ 1.  3.  1.]
T: [ 1.    1.    1.01]
m in C: -13.0
```

**What I've tried:**

I've also tried passing `P` in args, like so:

```
cons_c = [{'type':'ineq', 'fun': lambda N,P: 10 - sum(np.round(N)*P), 'args':P},{'type':'ineq', 'fun': lambda N: 24 - sum(N*T)}]
```

But it tells me `Lambda wants 2-arguments and received 4

** Update: **

using `(F,)` in `'args'` does not allow the program to run without raising an error, however the constraint still fails to hold up.

Also, `nan` is returned after `m` is defined as a negative value, which of course throws the whole scipy optimization out of wack.

** Full project code:**

```
import scipy.optimize
import numpy as np
import sys

def solve_utility(P,Q,T):
    """
    Here we are given the pricing already (P,Q,T), but solve for the quantities each type
    would purchase in order to maximize their utility (N).
    """

    def utility_a(N,P,Q,T):
        N = np.round(N)
        m = 50 - sum(N*P)
        b = sum(N*Q)
        t = 8 - sum(N*T)
        return 1/ ((b**0.5)*(t**0.5))+(5*(m**0.5))

    def utility_b(N,P,Q,T):
        N = np.round(N)
        m = 50 - sum(N*P)
        b = sum(N*Q)
        t = 8 - sum(N*T)
        return 1/ ((b**0.7)*(t**0.3))+(5*(m**0.5))

    def utility_c(N,P,Q,T):
        N = np.round(N)
        print "N: {0}".format(N)
        print "P: {0}".format(P)
        print "Q: {0}".format(Q)
        print "T: {0}".format(T)
        m = 10 - sum(N*P)
        b = sum(N*Q)
        t = 24 - sum(N*T)
        print "m in C: {0}".format(m)
        print "b: {0}".format(b)
        print "t: {0}".format(t)
        return 1/ ((b**0.3)*(t**0.7))+(5*(m**0.5))



    # Establishing constraints so no negative money or time:
    N = np.array([2,2,1])
    cons_a = [{'type':'ineq', 'fun': lambda N, P: 50 - sum(np.round(N)*P), 'args':(P,)},{'type':'ineq', 'fun': lambda N: 8 - sum(N*T)}]
    cons_b = [{'type':'ineq', 'fun': lambda N, P: 50 - sum(np.round(N)*P), 'args':(P,)},{'type':'ineq', 'fun': lambda N: 8 - sum(N*T)}]
    cons_c = [{'type':'ineq', 'fun': lambda N, P: 10 - sum(np.round(N)*P), 'args':(P,)},{'type':'ineq', 'fun': lambda N: 24 - sum(N*T)}]

    maxes = P/50
    bnds = [(0.,None) for x in range(len(N))]
    b = [()]

    optimized_a = scipy.optimize.minimize(utility_a, N, (P,Q,T), method='SLSQP', constraints=cons_a)
    optimized_b = scipy.optimize.minimize(utility_b, N, (P,Q,T), method='SLSQP', constraints=cons_b)
    optimized_c = scipy.optimize.minimize(utility_c, N, (P,Q,T), method='SLSQP', constraints=cons_c)

    if not optimized_a.success:
        print "Solving Utilities A didn't work..."
        return None
    if not optimized_b.success:
        print "Solving Utilities B didn't work..."
        return None
    if not optimized_c.success:
        print "Solving Utilities C didn't work..."
        return None
    else:
        print "returning N: {0}".format(np.array([optimized_a.x,optimized_b.x,optimized_c.x]))
        return np.array([optimized_a.x,optimized_b.x,optimized_c.x])


# solve_utility(P,Q,T,N)


def solve_profits():
    """ 
    Here we build the best pricing strategy to maximize solve_profits
    """

    P = np.array([   3,      10.67,       2.30]) # Pricing
    Q = np.array([   1,       4,       1]) # Quantity of beer for each unit
    T = np.array([   1,       1,    4]) # Time cost per unit
    N = np.array([   1,       0,       1]) # Quantities of unit taken by customer

    def profit(X):
        P,Q,T = X[0:3], X[3:6], X[6:9]
        Q[1] = round(Q[1]) # needs to be an integer
        N = solve_utility(P,Q,T)
        print "N: {0}".format(N)
        N = np.sum(N,axis=1)
        # print "P: {0}".format(P)
        # print "Q: {0}".format(Q)
        # print "T: {0}".format(T)
        denom = sum(N*P*Q) - sum(Q*N)
        return 1/ (sum(N*P*Q) - sum(Q*N))

    cons = [{'type':'ineq', 'fun': lambda X: X[8] - X[6] - 0.01 }, # The time expense for a coupon must be 0.01 greater than regular
            {'type':'ineq', 'fun': lambda X: X[4] - 2 }, # Packs must contain at least 2 beers
            {'type':'eq',   'fun': lambda X: X[3] - 1}, # Quantity has to be 1 for single beer
            {'type':'eq',   'fun': lambda X: X[5] - 1}, # same with coupons
            {'type':'ineq', 'fun': lambda X: X[6] - 1}, # Time cost must be at least 1
            {'type':'ineq', 'fun': lambda X: X[7] - 1}, 
            {'type':'ineq', 'fun': lambda X: X[8] - 1},
            ] 
    X = np.concatenate([P,Q,T])
    optimized = scipy.optimize.minimize(profit, X, method='L-BFGS-B', constraints=cons)

    if not optimized.success:
        print "Solving Profits didn't work..."
    else:
        return optimized.x, N

X, N = solve_profits()
print "X: {0} N {1}".format(X,N)
P,Q,T = X[0:3], X[3:6], X[6:9]
rev = sum(P * Q * N)
cost = sum(Q * N)
profit = (rev-cost)*50
print "N: {0}".format(N)
print "P: {0}".format(P)
print "Q: {0}".format(Q)
print "T: {0}".format(T)
print "profit = {0}".format(profit)
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you use round in your constraint ?

Comment: And I think it complains because it sees the list with three elements of P. Try `args = (P,)`

Comment: @Moritz still didn't work unfortunately

Comment: Hm,I can remember that I got violation of constraints using scipy.optimize.(cant remember which method). As a last resort (after you fixed the lambda function issue; maybe by using a function instead) you could switch to a different library or method. E.g lmfit. What happens if you use for example L-BFGS-B ?

Comment: Tried L-BFGS-B and still no luck

Comment: Is there a good reason for the rounding using np.round() ? Because you cut off the precision of the minimizer by rounding its value inside the function. The minimizer might try a step change of 1e-5 and it will become effectively 0.

Comment: I thought about that too. N needs to be an integer though .

Comment: well, then it is a discrete optimization case and the solver does not fit. It is supposed to optimize continuous problems. you could round afterwards but I am pretty sure that this might be the error. Alternatively, you could try for example https://github.com/perrygeo/simanneal

Comment: what is Q&T supposed to be in your function arguments? Also, if you want integer only values you need to use a branch and bound method. Basically, solve the continuous problem, and this is an upper bound value for your objective function. So the first step is to be able to solve the continuous problem. If you can post a complete and working example code I will have a look for you - I used scipy optimize quite heavily in a previous project.

Comment: @Chris `Q` is "quantity" and `T` is 'Time'. `P` is also 'price' and `N` is the amount of `Q`'s for price `P` the given person buys. I'll post the full code now.

Comment: @Moritz thanks for the link it looks really interesting, I'll try to implement it.

Comment: This looks like an [integer programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_programming) problem. You will get nowhere trying to solve a discrete optimization problem by gradient descent, since the "gradient" of your loss function is undefined if your parameters are discrete. [cvxopt](http://cvxopt.org/) contains solvers that might be suitable in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you isolate the for optimized_a and run, you see the error it throws is error 8 - this is the positive derivative error.

Both BFGS and SLSQP are gradient search methods, which means they take your initial guess, and evaluate the gradient and its derivative, and look for the best direction to take a step in, always stepping downhill and stopping when the change in value is either below the tolerance you set or it reaches a minimum.

The error suggests that (at least at your intial guess), the problem does not have a strong derivative. In general, SQLSP is best used on problems that can be formulated as a sum of squares. Perhaps trying more realistic initial guess would help. I would definitely discard most of the code and run a minimal example with optimized_a first, and once you get that working the rest can follow.

Perhaps a non gradient based solver would work, or depending on problem size and the realistic bounds you have on parameters, a global optimization may be workable.

scipy optimize is not great if you do not have a nice derivative to follow